# Resolving udisk-error-quark 4 when trying to format a disk

Tags: ssd, disk-formatting

I have a 128 GB ssd on an ubuntu 20.04.6 system and am trying to format it using the disk manager provided by the GUI. I am running into the error "udisk-error-quark 4". I have tried using the recommended command sudo gnome-disks but was unsuccessful. Any help would be appreciated.

[image: Error message]

[image: sudo gnome-disks output]

Answer (score 0):

I just had same problem trying to add a partition in free space in my 22.04 system.
I, at first, thought might be related to being on xrdp, but when logged in to physical machine got similar error.
I gave up added the partition while booted into a live USB.("Try ubuntu")